# 1998 4Runner Automatic Transmission problem

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission, 4runner

I attached a video of my 98 4Runner Automatic, I noticed my RPM would jump from 700-1900 RPMS when I let off the gas and then accelerate.

[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8UxmzD0lxc)

Is this a normal operation of the torque converter?